# Hide Home and Recent Button in Android App Programatically

Tags: java, android, android-homebutton, android-recents

[I need to hide Buttons in the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFmOf.jpg)
I need to hide Recent Button and Home Button if the My App is opened..
I have searched for so much codes. nothings seems to be working...
Please someone help me out.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide a better explanation.

Comment: just call setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) on your recent button view

Comment: Have attached the Image in question..Kindly check it

Comment: @MohanRaj : Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this topic, how to hide navigation bar, i think its that what u need

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation